# Find query in Mongodb based on two conditions

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I Have this documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae05907f3a9bd394c0065b8"), 
    "userName" : "Subhi", 
    "Password" : "123"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae08487b0c17d30c43f40b1"), 
    "userName" : "Omar", 
    "Password" : "123"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae0852945ec6f30c444a162"), 
    "userName" : "Subhi"
}
```

and I want to retrieve the number of the documents that matches the conditions, so I have to use something like this

```
db.users.find({"userName":"Subhi"}).count()
```

But this is only works for one condition, If i write it like this nothing will appear

```
  db.users.find({"userName":"Subhi","password":"123"}).count()
```

How I will write a mongodb statment that will return the number of the documents that matches the two conditions?

Comment: Typo. It's `"Password"` and not `"password"`. Otherwise no problem. Does not match because the case is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one maybe:

```
db.users.find( { $and: [ { userName:"Subhi" }, { password: "123" } ] } ).count()
```

Comment: sorry replace "userName" with username

Comment: @BenceUszkai It's no different to what the OP is already doing. `$and` is useless here since ALL MongoDB query conditions are already AND conditions.